# Cómo corregir el error ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'C:\\Users\\Usuario\\siiges-services\\public\\undefined?

Tags: error404

Cómo puedo solucionar el error

> message": ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'C:\Users\Usuario\siiges-services\public\undefined

Este es el código que lo genera:

```
// Internal dependencies const db = require('./db'); const fs = require('./fs');

function createData({ tipoDocumentoId, tipoEntidadId, entidadId }, nombre, ubicacion) { return { entidadId, nombre, tipoDocumentoId, tipoEntidadId, ubicacion, }; }

function getUbication({ tipoEntidad, tipoDocumento }, fileName) { return /uploads/${tipoEntidad}/${tipoDocumento}/${(fileName)}; }

async function uploadFile(fileMetdata, fileUploaded) { const identifierObj = await db.getFileIdentifierObj(fileMetdata); const previousFile = await db.findOneFile(identifierObj); const fileName = await fs.writeBus(fileUploaded, fileMetdata, previousFile);

            const ubication = getUbication(fileMetdata, fileName);
            const data = createData(identifierObj, fileName, ubication);

            if (previousFile) return db.updateFile(previousFile.id, data);

            return db.createFile(data);
            }

             module.exports = uploadFile;
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Título <> cuerpo de la pregunta. Aparte, no sabemos en qué función te muestra ese error. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.